# Binding a property of a user control in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, mvvm

I have a usercontrol I have created. **It is used within the DataTemplate of a list box.** 
The listbox is bound to an observable collection of custom objects.

I need a way to pass the current object to my usercontrol via binding.

I have tried to create a public property on the user control as such:

```
public TypedMediaItem CurrentItem { get; set; }
```

And set the binding parameters:

```
<my:LargeStreamItemControl Height="160" Width="295" CurrentItem="{Binding }" />
```

However this gives me the following error:

Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'F1MediaCentre.Classes.Payload.Typed.TypedMediaItem'.

I am unsure where I am going wrong - I am new to Silverlight, having inherited a live production application from a former colleague, and am racking my brains with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take a stab at this... it is possible that you can't bind to it because it is not a dependency property.

Add this to your user control in place of your current CurrentItem:

```
    Public Shared ReadOnly CurrentItemProperty As DependencyProperty = _
    DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentItem", GetType(TypedMediaItem), GetType(LargeStreamItemsControl), New PropertyMetadata(Nothing))
    Public Property CurrentItem() As TypedMediaItem
        Get
            Return DirectCast(GetValue(LargeStreamItemsControl.CurrentItemProperty), TypedMediaItem)
        End Get
        Set(value As TypedMediaItem)
            SetValue(LargeStreamItemsControl.CurrentItemProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property
```

Sorry I do mostly VB... hope you can convert to C# :)

This will make it a dependency property and therefore you'll be able to bind to it.

Okay, here's C#:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentItemProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentItem", typeof(TypedMediaItem), typeof(LargeStreamItemsControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
public TypedMediaItem CurrentItem 
{
    get { return (TypedMediaItem)GetValue(LargeStreamItemsControl.CurrentItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LargeStreamItemsControl.CurrentItemProperty, value); }
}
```